# AWS: downgrade Sql license for a single EC2 instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Let's say we have a regular EC2 instance in AWS with SQL Server license on the level of standard.
Is there an easiest way rather than building a new machine to migrate this instance to SqlServer WEB edition in Amazon? Or an instance with SQL Server Enterprise to SL Server standard. Basically a downgrade of the license.

Comment: Can you provide more information for this question? Are you self hosting these instances on EC2 or within RDS? Are you looking to migrate from EC2 to RDS? Is the move from SQL Standard to SQL Server a engine migration? I think that's what you're saying, sorry to be picky, but I should be able to answer it with a bit more information.

Comment: You are right, my bad! I've made a question more precise.

Comment: Is it a pre-existing license or did you get the license inside AWS? Like basically is the SQL Server license from an on-prem setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from my experience with AWS and the overall things I've read so far, I'm going to have a punt and say it's unlikely you'll be able to downgrade.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/08/sql-server-edition-change-standard-edition-enterprise-evaluation/

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=63321

These are forming my opinions on this.

From my experience, the best way you'd handle a migration here, would be to snapshot your EBS volumes/data, or use a backup facility to S3, then perform a restore of your data into a new instance. For DR and backup/restore, I would recommend using RDS in the future, it does have a few drawbacks, but ultimately it will assist a lot with migrating and allowing you to restore from older databases.

I'd also like to highlight that I've only done reading on your issue, so it could be possible, it's just that from what I've read and my experience, I don't think this would be possible using native tools.

Comment: It seems that you are right anyway and backup/restore is the only option. RDS sadly is impossible for our legacy architecture yet )

Comment: @aershov That's annoying, what are the reasons why you can't use RDS specifically? Are you using feature sets/root type stuff that you won't be able to access via RDS?

Comment: As I recall RDS does not allow to login on the server and we cannot yet separate database server and application physically

Comment: That seems fairly legitimate then, well good luck with your future architecture plans man, hopefully one day you'll be able to separate them!

Comment: Thanks, the day will sure come :)